# Can't access page using xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

I have an xmlhttprequest code that is executed on a button, it runs and access the advReqPage.aspx on the first run but when I press the button again, it doesn't access the advReqPage.aspx any more. What is the problem here?

```
function SaveAdvPayment() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var ornumber = document.getElementById("ORNumber").value;
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                // OK
                alert('response:' + xhr.responseText);
                // here you can use the result (cli.responseText)
            } else {
                // not OK
                alert('failure!');
            }
        }
    }
    xhr.open("GET", "Server_Requests/advReqPage.aspx?poo=" + ornumber + "&sess=INSERT", false);
    xhr.send();
    alert('Saved');
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
}
```

Comment: your code looks okay to me.  can you please post the more description about the error you are getting on browser console.  notice the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/stdeepak22/bympLdqa/ its just what you trying to do, and its working fine.

Comment: im not getting any error, it just that it's not accessing the AdvReqPage.aspx when I click it again

Comment: can you please put break point to this method, and see if its being hit in second time. and then trace further. so are you meaning `xhr.send` its not working as expected?

Comment: i added a break point and got this error
Exception was thrown at line 2, column 13011 in http://localhost:62026/Content/JavaScript/googleAPI.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError
Exception was thrown at line 2, column 13258 in http://localhost:62026/Content/JavaScript/googleAPI.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError
The thread '<No Name>' (0x198c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x22e0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: so it clearly shows error is not in your code you mentioned above. something wrong with google api

Answer (score 0):

Probably the first response is getting cached and when you make the second request your browser is not making this new request. This behavior is due to browser locking the cache and waiting to see the result of one request before requesting the same resource again. You can overcome this by making your requests unique like adding random query string.

Comment: I think you are right, I tried debugging on a different browser and it seems to be working now. Thanks!

Comment: how do you do that exactly? I don't usually use my account and post here. I apologize :)

Comment: Just click on the upward facing arrow on the left.